# Datepicker parses wrong date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

I click on the text field to open a datepicker, [image]

If I do not select a date, and just click anywhere on the screen, the datepicker displays wrong date, as shown

[image]

The code goes like this,

In edit.html.erb

```
<%= f.input :birthday, wrapper: :append do %>
  <%= f.text_field :birthday, :value => @user.birthday.try(:strftime,"%b %d, %Y"), :class => "datetime form-control", :'data-date-end-date' => Date.current.strftime('%m %d, %Y') %>
  <% end %>
<div class="form-group"></div>
<%= f.input :anniversary, wrapper: :append do %>
  <%= f.text_field :anniversary, :value => @user.anniversary.try(:strftime,"%b %d, %Y"), :class => "datetime form-control", :'data-date-end-date' => Date.current.strftime('%m %d, %Y') %>
<% end %>
```

In datepicker.js,

```
jQuery(document).on('focus', 'input.datetime', function() {
  opts =  {format: 'M dd, yyyy', autoclose: true};
  jQuery(this).datepicker(opts);
  jQuery(".datepicker").css("z-index",10000);
});
```

What can be done to get rid of such error?

Comment: This may be occur due to Bootstrap date-picker is selecting default date when you not select any date from calendar.

Comment: why not just turn autoclose as false